# Scala Abstract Types and Polymorphism

Tags: scala

[This Scala tutorial](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124) is confusing to me; the `Node` abstract type doesn't seem to following traditional rules of polymorphism...

```
type Node <: NodeIntf                // NodeIntf is assignable to Node.
abstract class NodeIntf {
  def connectWith(node: Node): Edge
}
class NodeImpl extends NodeIntf {
  def connectWith(node: Node): Edge = {
    val edge = newEdge(this, node)   // NodeImpl (this) is assignable to NodeIntf.
    edges = edge :: edges
    edge
  }
}
protected def newEdge(from: Node, to: Node): Edge
```

If `Node = NodeIntf` and `NodeIntf = NodeImpl`, then why can't we do `Node = NodeImpl`? I ask because apparently the above code won't compile - why must a 'self typed reference' be used? ([see tutorial](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You inverted the meaning of `<:`. A `Node` is assignable to a `NodeIntf`, that is:

```
val x: NodeIntf = y: Node
```

Now, further below you say `Node = NodeIntf` and `NodeIntf = NodeImpl`, which is not true. `Node` is an *arbitrary* subtype of `NodeIntf`, and `NodeImpl` is a specific subtype of `NodeIntf`.

In terms of *is a*, `Node` is a `NodeIntf`, and `NodeImpl` is a `NodeIntf`, but that has no meaning on the relationship between them -- you might as well have said that both `Node` and `NodeImpl` are both subtypes of `Any`.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, here is a sort-of minimal, self-contained version of your code:

```
abstract class Graph {
  type Node <: NodeIntf

  case class Edge(s: Node, d: Node)

  abstract class NodeIntf {
    def connectWith(node: Node): Edge
  }

  class NodeImpl extends NodeIntf {
    def connectWith(node: Node): Edge = {
      val edge = newEdge(this, node)
      edge
    }
  }

  def newEdge(from: Node, to: Node): Edge = Edge(from, to)
}
```

If you try to compile it, you'll get

```
found   : NodeImpl.this.type (with underlying type Graph.this.NodeImpl)
required: Graph.this.Node
    val edge = newEdge(this, node)
                       ^
```

The reason for the error message is, that `Node` is an **abstract** type. It has the upper bound `NodeIntf`, but it is nevertheless still abstract. That is, an implementation of the abstract `Graph` is free to set/bind `Node` to **any** subtype of `NodeIntf`.

In your code, you try to pass an instance of `NodeImpl` to `newEdge`, which expects a `Node`. You are right in that `NodeImpl` is a subtype of `NodeIntf`, however, an implementation of `Graph` might decide to restrict `Node` even further by binding it to a subtype of `NodeImpl`, which would make your call to `newEdge` illegal.

If you already bind `Node`, e.g., by making it a type alias of `NodeIntf`,

```
type Node = NodeIntf
```

then the above code compiles because later implementations of `Graph` cannot bind `Node` anymore.